# Robotic voice through iphone 6s microphone

Tags: ios, iphone, audio

I am developing an app to do live video streaming and when I recently upgraded to an iPhone 6s, all noise going through the microphone sounds robotic (or like a cricket). I can reproduce this issue only using the skype app, but no other app have this similar output. The skype support forums say that this is a problem they're seeing on iPhone 6s [1] but don't give any details as to what's causing it.

The interesting thing is it doesn't have issues when I use the microphone jack via my headphones, only when the built in microphone is used. Is there a permission or a change I need to make to my app to fix this?

[1] - http://community.skype.com/t5/iOS-iPhone-and-iPad/iPhone-6s-Distorted-sound/td-p/4138308

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 6S is apparently locked to a 48000 sample rate when using the built in microphone.  Maybe you tried to set the format to 44100.  I think the only way to deal with this is to query an active AVAudioSession for it's sampleRate property and set your format's sample rate to that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a know issue consumer users are seeing. It might be the iOS 9 update was not working properly.

Here's a source (might not be that trusted for some but it's a start)

http://9to5mac.com/2015/09/30/iphone-6s-touch-id-3d-touch-speaker-power-issues/

You can try a different app from the App Store, or call someone on speaker, to check if the issues is reproducible.

Comment: Interesting -- the issue is not reproducible on built in apps but skype has this problem as well. It's not a hardware issue because my sound recorder and facetime are not reproducing the issue

Comment: We have a VoIP app that is exhibiting the same problem.  I am banging my head against it right now, the OS is just doing something really weird.  No fix yet.  I wonder if Skype is as baffled as we are :(

Comment: BTW, the 9to5mac article is describing a different problem as far as I can tell.  This is specific to certain apps, and it's not loud or distorted, it's a "robot voice" as if it were going through a band pass filter.  The reason it sounds that way is because only every third audio buffer callback is succeeding -- so you have a carrier wave that is 1/3 the frequency of how often you get audio buffers.  As to WHY 2/3 of the callbacks are failing, I remain baffled.

Comment: Aaaaand, Skype fixed it.  Which means the pressure is on now for us to fix it too.  D'oh...

Comment: @user435779 So I've fixed the issue by changing the input sampling frequency to 48kHz instead of what it was set to before (16k or 32k depending on the circumstances.) The robotic voice goes away.